# Detecting a Linux box on a Windows network

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I would appreciate it if someone could advise me on how to get a Linux PC (or a Raspberry Pi) to be detected on a network that is meant for Windows machines. Are there any special broadcast packets sent out by a Linux machine that are identifiable?

Comment: You mean you want to have Samba shares or something?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you think there is an unknown or rogue device on the network, and you want to detect it. If it were me, I would start with a network scan. NMAP would be best, but anything at this point should work if you are familiar with what *should* be on the network. It can also help if you know all systems are supposed to be a certain brand (the OUI can give it away). Past that...depends on the network, architecture and what you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be interpreted in two ways: either wanting to find the IP address of your linux box (say a headless raspberry-pi connected to a network of windows computers), **or** wanting your windows computers to see your linux box in the network.

In the former case, you could [download](https://nmap.org/download.html) and install nmap on one of your windows computers, and run the following:

```
nmap -sV -p 22,53,110,143,4564 x.x.x.1-127
```

where x.x.x are the first three digits of your computer's IP address (e.g. 192.168.0, or 10.0.0). That launches a stealth SYN scan against each machine in your LAN. This will probably require you to the the Administrator of your computer or domain.

In the latter case, you can install samba packages (and ensure the daemons start automatically). The nmbd daemon will ensure that the linux box is visible from your windows computers. [This guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/samba-server-install-on-debian-7-wheezy) can help you with that.

Comment: Sorry, I think I am not being clear with my intention. Our office network administrator does not want any Linux machine on the network, as such I am wondering if putting one on the network could end up being detected. i.e. does traffic originating from a Linux machine has anything distinct which can be easily identified?

Comment: unless you are dong constant (scheduled) network scans with something that will do OS discovery, or you are using a proxy server which may be able to alert you on a non-windows user-agent, I think you're in trouble.